# Не вставляется картинка перед списком через ::before

Tags: html, css, псевдоэлемент

Я совсем новичок, не могу найти ошибку в коде. 
Не получается увидеть изображение, которое я пытаюсь подвязать через `::before` перед пунктами списка.
Картинка в коде распознается (проверила через f12, браузер ее видит). Проблема в том, что никак не получается задать `::before` высоту - ширина меняется, а высота ни в какую. 
 
Не помогли ни разные единицы измерения, ни `transform`, ни `overflow`, ни манипуляции с `background-size`, ни смена самой картинки на большой/маленький размер или на png.

Валидатор ошибок не нашел. 
Нужно именно через псевдоэлемент. Хеелп!!

```
<ul class="list">
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
</ul>
```

```
.list li{
    margin: 0 0 10px 0px;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-height: 20px;
}
.list li::before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: url('../img/icon2.svg') 0 0/20px 20px no-repeat;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: А размеры задать?

Comment: Да, явно проглядела. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display:flex` для `<li>`, чтобы стояли в ряд, а у псевдоэлемента явно задать ширину и высоту

```css
.list li{
    margin: 0 0 10px 0px;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-height: 20px;
    display: flex;
}
.list li::before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: url('../img/icon2.svg') 0 0/20px 20px no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Все получилось)